# How many possibilities of merging two queues?

Tags: queues

Say there're two queues of numbered items of different kinds (e.g. color), now we need to merge them into one queue so that each item maintains its order in the original queue, regardless of its kind.

For example,

queue of blacks balls: b1, b2, b3

queue of red balls: r1, r2

one possible merging result: b1, b2, r1, b3, r2

given size of two queues being `m` and `n`, derive an expression of total possibilities of merging? I feel like it can be solved with dynamic programming but still have no clue...

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it should be $2^{m+n-1}$, where $m,n$ are sizes of the queues respectively. You can see it this way - you will have $m+n$ places to fill and at every place, there will be two choices - you can either place it from the first queue or the second queue.

Comment: That is not correct.  Try it on some special cases.  For instance, try $n=1,m=1$.  In particular, if one queue is empty by the time you reach a place, then there is only 1 legal choice.

Comment: @D.W. Oh, fair enough, I realised my solution seemed too simple. I'll let my comment stay for someone who makes the same mistake as me I suppose.

Comment: @mzoz What about $m+n \choose m$? The final list will have $m+n$ places and out of this, we can choose $m$ places where the elements from the first queue will be placed, and the rest taken by the elements of second queue. Also, since we are not permuting, the relative order of elements is also maintained.

Comment: @Gokul I think you're right! Thanks! time to revise combination/permutation knowledge lol